# raise ImproperlyConfigured( django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django

> raise ImproperlyConfigured(
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
> INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either
> define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
> settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Unable to figure out the reason of the error.

Below is my settings.py:

```
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.9.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
import category.context_processors

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-(@pq@&r(t2tm_m8ci@$%z_z^l+kbnxdyd5#_+h8ckafos&8b5*'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'category',
    'accounts',
    'store',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'greatkart.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'category.context_processors.menu_links',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'greatkart.wsgi.application'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    'greatkart/static',
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# media files configuration

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

Below is my context processors:

```
from .models import Category
def menu_links(request):
    links = Category.objects.all()
    return dict(links=links)
```

Below is my category models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    cat_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/categories', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('products_by_Category', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: You must have remove the starting quotes from the settings.py by mistake. Kindly add `"""` in the beginning of settings.py. Right now all your other settings are just being read as a string

Comment: That is already there, it was not pasted here by mistake. However the issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

you must remove the starting double quotes in the settings.py

Comment: It did not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code in settings.py:

```
    """
    Django settings for greatkart project.
    
    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.9.
    
    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/
    
    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
    """
    
    from pathlib import Path
    
    # Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    
    
    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/
    
    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-t*t_%wa66s=h+zo0nw^#x)!s#omgu^m@hm^-9pb2u!ql90lfu5'
    
    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True
    
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
    
    
    # Application definition
    
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'category',
        # 'accounts',
        # 'store',
    ]
    
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]
    
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'greatkart.urls'
    
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates'],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                    'category.context_processors.menu_links',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
    
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'greatkart.wsgi.application'
    
    
    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases
    
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }
    
    
    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
    
    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]
    
    
    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/
    
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
    
    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
    
    USE_I18N = True
    
    USE_L10N = True
    
    USE_TZ = True
    
    
    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
    
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        'greatkart/static',
    ]
    
    
    # Default primary key field type
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field
    
    DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this issue for wrong command i think you also faced this issue for same reason so you can try this command

```
python .\manage.py runserver 8000
```

and you must add triple double quotes in your setting.py

```
"""
```